# how to plot time series where x-axis is datetime.time object in matplotlib?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to graph timeseries data beginning from 9pm to 6pm the next day. Here is my failed attempt.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import time    

a=np.array([35,25,24,25,27,28,30,35])
df=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range("00:00", "23:00", freq="3H").time,data={'column1':a})

          column1
00:00:00       35
03:00:00       25
06:00:00       24
09:00:00       25
12:00:00       27
15:00:00       28
18:00:00       30
21:00:00       35
```

reindexing data to go from 21:00 to 18:00. perhaps there is a better way of achieving this part too, but this works.

```
df=df.reindex(np.concatenate([df.loc[time(21,00):].index,df.loc[:time(21,00)].index[:-1]]))

          column1
21:00:00       35
00:00:00       35
03:00:00       25
06:00:00       24
09:00:00       25
12:00:00       27
15:00:00       28
18:00:00       30

plt.plot(df.index,df['column1'])
```

the x-axis does not seem to match df.index. also the axis begins at 00:00 not 21:00. does anyone know a solution that doesn't involve using string labels for the x-axis?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that is to plot the data without expliciting the x axis and the to change the labels. The problem is that this will only works if the time between the data is constant. I know you said you didn't want to use string labels, so I don't know of this solution will be what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import time    

a=np.array([35,25,24,25,27,28,30,35])

df=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range("00:00", "23:00",freq="3H").time,data={'column1':a})

df=df.reindex(np.concatenate([df.loc[time(21,00):].index,df.loc[:time(21,00)].index[:-1]]))

# Now we create the figure and the axes
fig,axes=plt.subplots()
axes.plot(df['column1'])  # In the x axis will appear 0,1,2,3...
axes.set_xticklabels(df.index)  # now we change the labels of the xaxis

plt.show()
```

This should do the trick and will plot what you want.

[image: example of result]